# Elasticsearch, Kibana seesm slow, how to split index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm creating an index for log data, each day about 100K documents are indexed.

I find viewing data through kibana is bit sluggish.

Each day, an index like `log-2019-04-11' is created, and I'm using`log*` as index pattern to view the data in kibana.

I am using single node, and only changed `Xms8g Xmm8g` for ES configuration.

** edit **

I know there are concept of shard, but I haven't touched(configured) anything relaed to shard (such as in elasticsearch.yml)

```
GET /analytics-prod*/_stats/
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 550,
    "successful" : 275,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 5128749,
        "deleted" : 0
      },
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 4396388356
      },
```

One day data  size is about..

```
GET /analytics-prod-2019.04.14/_stats/                                                                                                                                                                                              [55/1894]
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 68912,
        "deleted" : 0
      },
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 67331653
      },
```

I have two comp, first one is faster one, but I'd like to run ES on slower one if possible.

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              6
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-5
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  6
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             800.041
CPU max MHz:         4100.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            5808.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            9216K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-5



=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST2000DM006-2DM164
Serial Number:    Z560A76X
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 09286b712
Firmware Version: CC26
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Apr 15 19:01:32 2019 KST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

another computer has the following cpu / hdd

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               58
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             1694.098
CPU max MHz:         3400.0000
CPU min MHz:         1600.0000
BogoMIPS:            6799.84
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue
Device Model:     WDC WD10EZEX-00RKKA0
Serial Number:    WD-WMC1S5459395
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 0ae471bd6
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Apr 15 19:02:20 2019 KST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

GET _cat/nodes?v

```
ip           heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
192.168.0.57           72          88   4    0.60    0.72     0.61 mdi       *      3tf0hMb
```

GET analytics-prod-2019.04.01/_mapping

It is too big to paste here, I saved the output and printed the line count

`$ cat a.json | wc -l
772`

```
 {
   "analytics-prod-2019.04.01" : {
     "mappings" : {
       "doc" : {
         "properties" : {
           "@timestamp" : {
             "type" : "date"
           },
           "@version" : {
             "type" : "text",
             "fields" : {
               "keyword" : {
                 "type" : "keyword",
                 "ignore_above" : 256
               }
             }
           },
           "batch_no" : {
             "type" : "text",
             "fields" : {
               "keyword" : {
                 "type" : "keyword",
                 "ignore_above" : 256
               }
             }
           },
           "data" : {
             "properties" : {
               "anonymousId" : {
                 "type" : "text",
                 "fields" : {
                   "keyword" : {
                     "type" : "keyword",
                     "ignore_above" : 256
                   }
                  }
                }
              },
              "channel" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "context" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "app" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "build" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "name" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "namespace" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                      "namespace" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "version" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "device" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "adTrackingEnabled" : {
                        "type" : "boolean"
                      },
                      "advertisingId" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "id" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                      "id" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "manufacturer" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "model" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "name" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "library" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "name" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "version" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "locale" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                      "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "network" : {
```

.. it keeps going I've pasted about 1/4th of the whole output.

Comment: how big is your index, how many shards, how many cpu and ram and what type of hdd are u using?

Comment: @DejanMarić I've added the info you requested, let me know if there's anything else needed..

Comment: please add more info, number of nodes and mapping of your index, GET index_name/_mapping and GET _cat/nodes?v

Comment: @DejanMarić I added the outputs of the commnands you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Your daily data is pretty much small (about 64MB). You don't need 5 shards for a such small index. Recommended size for shard is `10-40GB` which means that you are oversharding your node. When performing search requests on 10 indexes with 5 shards, you need to go to 50 shards total (and you have only 1 node as I can see). If you reduce that to 1 shard, it will go only to 10 shards.

In case you want to do more parallel search requests on your data, try to put more replicas (If you have 6 nodes, try adding up to 5 replicas). Maybe you could try to put in monthly index instead of daily, `100k` docs per day is very small.

Java heap should be about 50% of your RAM (if you have `64GB` of RAM, put `Xms30g Xmm30g`, don't put it more than this, because of Java pointers - [more info](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/35gb-heap-less-32gb-java-jvm-memory-oddities/)).

Also, you need to set your mapping or template properly. Elasticsearch did it for you, but I guess you are not doing any full text search analysis on most of the fields, so you can put them as `keyword` in predefined mapping - [more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping.html)

Last thing, you should use `SSD` instead of spinning disk for more and faster I/O operations.